# How to create PDF documents from image files, using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

With PHP application, I have to generate single PDF documents, from set of images.

Which is best way to achieve this? Can I use TCPDF library, and can you give me some example?

Comment: FPDF.org is a library we have used at our company (a coworker of mine; I can't vouch for it personally).

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to use TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org) and set the images as full background as on the example n. 51.

For example:

```
// disable auto-page-break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

// set image 1
$pdf->AddPage();
$this->Image('image_demo1.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$this->setPageMark();

// set image 2
$pdf->AddPage();
$this->Image('image_demo2.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$this->setPageMark();

// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [dompdf](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).You can find a copy of the original documentation at [this link](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirements but ImageMagick could probably do the trick. I believe that they also have a php wrapper available for all the image manipulation/conversion functions.