# How to convert a series of images into one pdf document in php

Tags: php, imagick

I have searched for a while and can not find a clear answer to this.

I have a folder with images:
001.png, 002.png ....etc.

what I have tried.

```
$allImages = 'folder/001.png folder/002.png folder/003.png';
//and
$allImages = 'folder/001.png,folder/002.png,folder/003.png';
//and
$allImages = '-adjoin folder/001.png -adjoin folder/002.png -adjoin folder/003.png';
```

then:

```
exec(convert $allImages folder/newdoc.pdf);
//and
exec(convert -density 150 -format pdf{} ".$all_images folder/newdoc.pdf);
```

This only puts one page into the pdf and the pdf has a header of png so it really is not readable by a pdf viewer.

I do not want to use (convert *.png newdoc.pdf) as i need the pdf in a certain sequence. EDIT: this does not work either.

Comment: Try setting them up in an array instead, such as `$allImages = array("folder/001.png", "folder/002.png", "folder/003.png");` and without seeing your entire code or knowing which PDF library you're using, is hard to elaborate any more than this.

Comment: Googling `imagemagick multiple files to pdf` provides many solutions. Have you tried them all?

Comment: [Converting multiple image files from JPEG to PDF format](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29869)

Comment: @pekka, almost all the solutions are with wildcards which i do not want.

Comment: @Fred I am using Imagick

Comment: @Fred and @ Pekka, I think it is a memory issue. seems to work until the combined image sizes become greather than 1.3 meg. any ideas?

Comment: @SmithSmithy Sorry I don't. Only thing I can suggest is that you check your memory max settings in `php.ini` and increase if possible. You could probably use this in your code also `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');` increase as required. Have a look at this also, may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660603/1415724

Comment: @SmithSmithy You're welcome. I edited my comment above with a link to an answer. Three ways of increasing memory.

Comment: If you dont mind, try using TCPDF. It can solve all your purposes with PDF documents and has dedicated functions to add page in PDF. I am always using it for putting images in and graphs in different pages.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865651/how-to-create-pdf-documents-from-image-files-using-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865651/how-to-create-pdf-documents-from-image-files-using-php

Comment: I would really use TCPDF to do the job here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865651/how-to-create-pdf-documents-from-image-files-using-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865651/how-to-create-pdf-documents-from-image-files-using-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mPDF. All the information you need is here: [mPDF Github project](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf)

Comment: I have not been here in a while so I did not see all of these answers. As it turns out mPDF was the solution. I tried them all and mPDF was the best hands down!

Comment: Excellent @SmithSmithy I'm glad that everything has gone ok

Comment: every link is death

Comment: @Antu I just update the info. I hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

From looking at imagemagick.org I would conclude it to work like this:

```
$allImages = '-adjoin folder/001.png -adjoin folder/002.png -adjoin folder/003.png';
exec("convert $allImages folder/newdoc.pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This does not throw any errors but i am still getting a pdf with a file header of PNG and only one page.

Comment: convert -adjoin folder/001.png -adjoin folder/002.png -adjoin folder/003.png -format pdf folder/newdoc.pdf

Answer (score 1):

FPDF is all need, see this tutorial page: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm
And here you can find the manual: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php

Do something similar like this example:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
foreach($pictures as $picture) {
    $pdf->Image($image,'0','0');
    $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into this old question

[How can I convert a series of images to a PDF from the command line on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955425/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-images-to-a-pdf-from-the-command-line-on-linux)

you can use imagemagick for this.