# Trying to use my uploadImage function for pdf upload

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload, image-uploading

Im uploading images using a uploadImage function.

Now Im trying to upload also pdf,making some changes, with same function and not creating other, but Im not having sucess.

Is there any method like imagejpeg() and so on for pdf, so I can do someting like this to upload to my folder:

```
case 'pdf': filepdf($new_img, $folder.$name); break;
```

Sure I dont want the resize part and treat the effects of transparency,blending, etc, but I just wanted to take the part of upload the file to the folder but its not working.

```
function uploadImage($tmp, $name, $width, $folder){
        $ext = substr($name,-3);

        switch($ext){
            case 'jpg': $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp); break;
            case 'png': $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp); break;
            case 'gif': $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp); break; 

        }       
        $x = imagesx($img);
        $y = imagesy($img);
        $height = ($width*$y) / $x;
        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        imagealphablending($new_img,false);
        imagesavealpha($new_img,true);
        imagecopyresampled($new_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $x, $y);

        switch($ext){
            case 'jpg': imagejpeg($new_img, $folder.$name, 100); break;
            case 'png': imagepng($new_img, $folder.$name); break;
            case 'gif': imagegif($new_img, $folder.$name); break;   
        }
        imagedestroy($img);
        imagedestroy($new_img);
    }
```

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865651/how-to-create-pdf-documents-from-image-files-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but you could try something like this... It checks for MIME types, which is better than your current method. Might make sense to rename it something like `uploadFile` rather than `uploadImage` as well. And the `$width` variable no longer makes sense for non-image files.

```
function uploadImage($tmp, $name, $width, $folder) {
    // initialize variables
    $img = $ext = null;

    // supported file types
    $valid_mimes = array('pdf' => 'application/pdf',
                         'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                         'png' => 'image/png',
                         'gif' => 'image/gif');

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if ($ext = array_search($finfo->file($tmp), $valid_mimes, true)) {
        switch($ext) {
            case 'pdf': move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.$name); break;
            case 'jpg': $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp); break;
            case 'png': $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp); break;
            case 'gif': $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp); break;
        }

        if (isset($img)) {
            $x = imagesx($img);
            $y = imagesy($img);
            $height = ($width*$y) / $x;
            $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            imagealphablending($new_img,false);
            imagesavealpha($new_img,true);
            imagecopyresampled($new_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $x, $y);

            switch($ext) {
                case 'jpg': imagejpeg($new_img, $folder.$name, 100); break;
                case 'png': imagepng($new_img, $folder.$name); break;
                case 'gif': imagegif($new_img, $folder.$name); break;
            }
            imagedestroy($img);
            imagedestroy($new_img);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I´ll test it now, but where you wrote 'png': move_uploaded_files($tmp, $folder.$name); break; you wanted to write pdf right?

Comment: It is saying that class finfo its not found!

Comment: It worked, I needed to do some configuration on php.ini file. Thank you :)